# Forcing Google Docs to display the desktop version

Tags: google-drive

I have to change my user agent to "iPhone" so that I can get connected to the internet through my smartphone.

The problem is that I can get the desktop versions of many sites even the Google Docs start page. But, when I choose a document to view/edit, It opens the mobile mobile. I tried to put some arguments to force the desktop version (ex : ...&nomobile=1) but it is not working.

How can I force the desktop version to be shown in Google Docs on my phone?

Comment: If the page uses CSS `@media` types, then changing the useragent or URL queries will do little, since the CSS can be strictly defined by display dimensions.

Answer (score 2):

To force the desktop version add `overridemobile=true` to the URL:

https://drive.google.com/?&overridemobile=true

Comment: This does not work (anymore).

Comment: It's `?fd=true` now.

Comment: even fd is not working now.

Comment: fd=true works for me (2022)

Answer (score 1):

To force desktop version in your mobile browser use:
https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0?fd=true

This works in the Chrome App in iOS at least.

Comment: How can I make it work for googl docs and Google spreadsheet?